# Assign statement in testbench doesn't seem to work as it should

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, testbench

I have a small Verilog code example asked as an interview question. I am not sure why it prints "p=01" but not "00" since `assign` should update `p` as soon as the value of `q` changes. Or does it work differently in a testbench?

```
module tb;
  
  reg [1:0] p,q;
  
   assign p=q;
  
  initial begin
    q=1;
    #100 
    q=0;
    $display("p  =  %b",p);
  end
    
endmodule
```

I am using Mentor Questa in [edaplayground](https://edaplayground.com/x/tRqA). Even if I make `p` a `wire`, the result is the same.

Comment: What simulator are you using? Strictly, having `p` on the left side of the assign is invalid because `p` is a `reg` type. What happens if you make `p` a `wire` instead? Also do you want an answer for Verilog or System Verilog?

Comment: Using Mentor Questa in edaplayground. Even if I make p  a wire, the result is the same.  https://edaplayground.com/x/tRqA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interview question looks like it was taken directly from the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 4.8 *Race conditions*

> Because the execution of expression evaluation and net update events
> may be intermingled, race conditions are possible
>
> The simulator is correct in displaying either a 1 or a 0. The
> assignment of 0 to `q` enables an update event for `p`. The simulator may
> either continue and execute the `$display` task or execute the update
> for `p`, followed by the `$display` task.

In your case, a simulator may display `00` or `01`.

One way to avoid the race is to delay the `$display`:

```
  initial begin
    q=1;
    #100 
    q=0;
    #1;
    $display("p  =  %b",p);
  end
```

In writing Verilog code, always strive to avoid race conditions.

It does not matter if `p` is declared as a `reg` or a `wire`.  Note that declaring as `reg` is only allowed in your code example if SystemVerilog features are enabled in your simulator.